# Host the published site in nopcommerce

Tags: nopcommerce

I am working in ecommerce website using NopCommerce2.2. I hosted the website by copying the complete source code in the wwwroot of the dotnet panel. It was working fine. But the size was huge. It was around 700MB. So I published the Nop.Web and its Administration. The site was working fine in the localhost(i.e local server) using IIS7. But when I copied the contents directly to the wwwroot in the global server,it was redirecting to the error page `errorpage.htm?aspxerrorpath=/` instead of the site. Can anyone suggest a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Copy your website (all folders and content) from your development computer to  an application folder on your remote hosting computer (server).

Make sure the bin folder, on your remote hosting computer, contains the same dll files as on your development computer.

Copy Your Data

If your application contains data or a database. For instance an SQL Server Compact database (a .sdf file in App_Data folder), consider the following:

Do you want to publish your test data to the remote server?

Most likely not.

If you have test data on your development computer, it may overwrite production data on your remote hosting computer.

If you have to copy an SQL database (.sdf file), perhaps you should delete everything in the database, and then copy the empty .sdf file from your development computer to the server.

THAT'S IT. GOOD LUCK !

Answer (score 1):

```
You need to follow the following steps as I mentioned
```

For Publishing the NopCommerce Application website below is the step:

Step : 1 - Publish the Nop.Web project.

Step : 2 - Publish the Nop.Admin project.

Go to the publish folder where your publish created

Step : 3 - Cut all dll from the Administration and Paste all dll to bin folder which in main bin folder for whole project.

Step : 4 - Copy two things from your source project and in App_Data folder Settings.txt and InstalledPlugins.txt which is not published in your publish file so paste this two files in your publish folder in App_Data. (You need to change the connection string in Setting.txt as per your database host).

Step : 5 - Now you need to copy whole plugins folder from your source folder (but remember this plugins folder you need to copy from the Presentation folder not from the main source where the solution file are there.).

Step : 6 - Now your publish have been ready.(now you can deploy on hosting server)